# Firefox: how to display more download status in the drop-down menu of downloads

Tags: firefox

I'm talking about the drop-down menu that can be displayed by hitting the Downloads button that's a gray or blue, downward arrow icon, with the tooltip that says "Display the progress of ongoing downloads".

By default, it only displays 3 downloads. To see more, I have to click "+ X Downloads" or "Show All Downloads" and it opens up a separate window titled "Library". I'd like to check like 30 most recent downloads directly in the drop-down menu. Is there an add-on or something for this?

Comment: I thought you would be able to do that by tweaking some parameters in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), but couldn't find anything… Is using [an add-on](http://addons.mozilla.org/) acceptable for you?